# Create small padding around bootstrap4 div with container-fluid class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am creating a minimal SPA using bootstrap 4.x.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .dropbtn {
          background-color: #4CAF50;
          color: white;
          font-size: 16px;
          border: none;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        .dropdown {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        
        .dropdown-content {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          background-color: #f9f9f9;
          min-width: 160px;
          box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
          z-index: 1;
        }
        
        .dropdown-content a {
          color: black;
          padding: 12px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: block;
        }
        
        .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
        
        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
          display: block;
        }
        
        .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
          background-color: #3e8e41;
        }
    </style>    

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">File</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            Content here ...
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I noticed that when I view the page in a browser, there is no padding at all around the containing (parent) div, and everything seems squashed against the edges. I would like to add a small amount of padding (say 3px) around the entire container - however, when I use a simple (quick and dirty) solution like adding style attribute: `style="padding 3px;"` to the parent div, the layout is completely messed up.

How do I fix my CSS so that I can apply a small padding to the container div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it to `body` tag instead of `container-fluid` because `container-fluid` has its own paading. or add your custom container to `container-fluid` and add padding to it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
body{
  padding: 3px;
}
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
  </style>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">File</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
          <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
          <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      Content here ...
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```